# Change behavior based on template enum parameter

Tags: c++, templates, enums, template-specialization

I've got a communication class which can handle 2 different protocols. The protocol is chosen by a enum template variable.
Now 1 of the 2 protocols only supports 2-byte values while the other supports 4-byte values.
Communicating is done via a template member function. How to change the static_assert so it takes 2 or 4 bytes depending on the class specialization (= chosen protocol)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

enum Protocol { P1, P2 };


template <Protocol P>
class Communicator {
  public:
    template <typename T>
    void communicate(T arg) {
      static_assert(sizeof(arg) <= sizeof(float), "argument size must be <= 4 bytes");
      float value = (float)arg;
      uint8_t length = sizeof(arg);  //length in bytes
      _communicate(value, length);
    }

    void _communicate(float f, uint8_t length) {
      std::cout << f;
    }
};
```

EDIT: I can just pick 1 answer as correct. And although I learned the most from Roy, I picked MM's answer because it keeps things as simple as possible. (upvoted both though)

Comment: Why a template if it's just to down cast the eventual double or (long) long integer into a float?  Maybe it would be best to just accept a float and let an eventual compiler warning tell the caller exactly what will happen to his precision when using the class, if needed.

Comment: @MichaelRoy The library is intended for Arduino users. I doubt they look at the compiler warnings (disabled by default). But you've got a very valid point! I will look into the program's design.

Comment: `((P == P1) ? 2 : 4)` would probably be fine too

Comment: @M.M is it really as simple as that? (because you say "probably")

Comment: M.M. has a very valid point.

Comment: @BMelis I can't think of any reason why not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's several ways to approach this... here is one:

```
template<Protocol P>
size_t value_size();

template<> size_t value_size<P1>() { return 2; }
template<> size_t value_size<P2>() { return 4; }

// ... inside your other function
static_assert(sizeof(arg) <= value_size<P>(),
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdint>

// enum Protocol { P1, P2 };  // let's use types with traits instead.

struct P1
{
    constexpr static const int protocol_id = 1; 
                           //^^ or maybe use an enum 
                           // type, this may need refactoring
                           // to fit your code and style.
    using data_type = uint16_t;  //< or whatever your 2-byte datatype is.

    // can add more data traits and even static member functions here

    // you could also add protocol specific non-static data if you add a 
    // P1 data member to your Communicator class.

    // A struct with traits is a very good entry point for many compile-time
    // polymorphism techniques.
};

struct P2
{
    constexpr static const int protocol_id = 2;
    using data_type = uint32_t;  //< or whatever your 4-byte datatype is.
};


template <typename _Proto>
class Communicator {
  public:
      using data_type = typename _Proto::data_type;
      constexpr static const int proto_id = typename _Proto::protocol_id;

  public:
    void communicate(data_type arg) // we can use the trait from either P1 or P2
   {
      float value = (float)arg;
      uint8_t length = sizeof(data_type);  //length in bytes
      _communicate(value, length);
    }

    void _communicate(float f, uint8_t length) 
    {
      std::cout << f;
    }
};
```

Here's code to convert an enum (If that's what you already have to a class.

```
enum protocol_t { p1, p2 };

template <protocol_t _p> struct Protocol {};

// simply derive the template specialization from the desired type
template <> struct Protocol<p1> : P1 {};
// simply derive the template specialization from the desired type
template <> struct Protocol<p2> : P2 {};
```

You can also derive from P1, P2 to help organize code.

```
struct P1
{
   // ... + specialized functions:
   void _communicate(value_type x) { ... }  // that you'll call from Communicator
   void _communicate(const value_type* begin, const value_type* end) { ... }
};

struct P2 { /* same thing */ };

template <typename _Proto>
class Communicator : _Proto // < can control visibility here.
{ ... };
```